# How can I delete storage File?

Tags: android

Version Android SDK 5.1

I do this Code.

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
String innerPath = "/xxxx/strage/Download/"
StringPath = path + innerPath;

File[] files = new File(targetPath).listFiles();
for(File f:files){
f.delete();
}
```

after execute this code, I checked Dir by "FileCommander.apk" I confirm deleted.
but when conect this Android to PC And Check this Directory, not deleted.

Please help me.

Comment: is it giving any error in logcat ?

Comment: did you give write external storage permission

Comment: @Lucifer  thanks. these is none error Message in logcat

Comment: @Vasant thanks. it's solved. but I have a one question. it's Android File Commander can't display Files but when Connect Android to PC, in PC I can watch deleted Files. why Reason

Comment: @CCPdev, what is that ?

Comment: Have you added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> in mainifest??.

Comment: @Lucifer Sorry I missed.

Comment: @RahulGiradkar thanks. yes. I have.

Comment: that is a known Android problem that it doesn't update the file list to show on the PC immediapely. There is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Cant the media store be informed about the deletes? I think it can.

Comment: `f.delete();`. It is nice that you used a file explorer app to check if the directory became empty. But before you should better your code as delete() returns true or false. You should have checked that to begin with.

Comment: @Vladyslav Matviienko thanks. I would like to close this question, I'm sorry, could you describe your comment as "Answer"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unfortunately a [known old Android bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36956498), which google does not care about.

In short:
Sometimes depending on the way the file was created, it is not showing in the media device storage, when Android device is connected to the PC as MTP device. They should appear (or disappear in your case) after reboot, but there are known situations when reboot didn't help too.

Answer (score 1):

```
 File file= new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"MyFolder"); // My Folder is Folder
    if (file.isDirectory())
    {
        listFile = file.listFiles();


        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++)
        {
     if(String.valueOf(listFile[i].getAbsoluteFile()).equals("/storage/emulated/0/MyFolder/Adu.jpg")){//absolute path
             File f=new File(String.valueOf(listFile[i].getAbsoluteFile()));
             f.delete();
        }

            Log.d(myTag, "Response :  "+listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String innerPath = "/xxxx/strage/Download/"
```

seems like strage is written wrong. 
shouldnt it mean `String innerPath = "/xxxx/storage/Download/"` ?